# parsing Opendata JSON with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, dataset

I Have this project where I want to get the JSON data from an Open [Dataset](http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v1/bevolking/inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict.json). I need to use NodeJS to get this JSON info from this dataset and pass it to angular. The problem is that I'm passing a JSON-file instead of a JSON object so I can't use the usual Angular functions like `ng-repeat` on this data.
I'm guessing I need to Parse this JSON in NodeJS first, but HOW do I do this? How do I parse this JSON and only pass the requested objects back to my angular?

NodeJS code for getting the full JSON from the dataset to Angular:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    request("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v1/bevolking/inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict.json").pipe(res);
})
```

so I angular I will get the entire JSON, but this is neither efficient/fast, nor is it possible for me to handle the data in Angular.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like you pipe the string "filename" to response, you should read the file end return the content

Comment: I think I am getting sending the content to Angular, right? see here the screenshot from my Angular's console.log of the response : http://oi65.tinypic.com/2v2wp4i.jpg

Comment: ok, so you got an array, what's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the url you gave and it returns an object which contain an array of objects. I guess you want the ng-repeat to run through that array vs the top parent object?

if you know the top parent key (which was 'inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict' when I tested) you can tell angular to use it, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj.inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict"> ... </div>
```

which will tell angular to run through the array.

If you want to handle this at the node level, you can do the following:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    request("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v1/bevolking/inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict.json", function (error, response, body) {
        if ( error || response.statusCode != 200)
            return (res.status (response.statusCode).end ()) ;
        var data =JSON.parse (body) ;
        res.json (data.inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict) ;
    });
}) ;
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much ;) Here's another question. As you can see this json has multiple object with key "gebieden" with the same value. The problem is that when I do a ng-repeat on all objects and want their value for "gebieden" to be shown, I will (for example) have 3 divs with conent "antwerpen". How do I make sure I don't use doubles ?

Comment: You need to use the unique keyword in your ng-repeat directive, add someting like:  | unique:'gebieden' - 
and accept the answer ;)

Comment: I did use that but it doesn't work gives back >Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: if you could share your code, I can take a look later today, vs me rewriting all from scratch - and may be post this unique question as a new question?